# Verifying my proof in intuitionistic logic

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I need to prove that $ \neg Kp \rightarrow \neg p$ follows **intuitionistically** from $ p \rightarrow \neg \neg Kp$. May I ask someone to verify my proof?

[image]

In addition, I also possess a proof for $\forall p (\neg Kp \rightarrow \neg p)$ is equivalent **intuitionistically** to $\neg \exists p (p \wedge \neg Kp)$. The proof is a bit long so I won't post it here. May I also ask someone to verify that the two are indeed equivalent **intuitionistically**? Thanks very much.

Comment: You need to assume $\lnot Kp$ before you assume $P$.  You can't do RAA with outstanding assumptions between the 2 contradictory points.

Comment: Also it is really bad style to use $p$ to refer to 2 different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your proof correctly, I think it is fine. That said, you can abstract from the problem greatly.

You can intuitionistically prove $(A\land B)\to C \iff A\to(B\to C)$. Often $\neg P$ is *defined* as $P\to\bot$ in intuitionistic logic, but it can certainly be shown to be provably equivalent to it. (You can show $\bot\iff P\land\neg P$ if you don't have $\bot$ as a connective.) Combined with $(\exists x.P(x))\to C\iff\forall x.(P(x)\to C)$ (which is secretly very closely related to the earlier equivalence), this gives you the second statement by using $A=\neg Kp$, $B=p$, and $C=\bot$ for the inner formula after applying the previous equivalence.

Of course, we can easily prove $A\land B \iff B\land A$ and thus with the above we easily have $A\to(B\to C)\iff B\to(A\to C)$. Your first statement is an example of this with $A=p$, $B=\neg Kp$, and $C=\bot$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I realize that I used RAA in my proof. But it seems that we cannot use RAA in intuitionistic logic as a result of omitting the law of exclusive middle. May I please ask if we can use RAA? If not, how to fix this part of the proof?

Comment: Argh. This is a [common misunderstanding](https://www.hedonisticlearning.com/posts/the-pedagogy-of-logic-a-rant.html#the-complete-conflation-of-negation-introduction-with-double-negation-elimination). There are (essentially) two rules that "reductio ad absurdum" can refer to. The first is: "If $P\implies\bot$, then $\neg P$." This is often taken as an axiom in intuitionistic systems and called "negation introduction". The other rule is: "if $\neg P\implies\bot$, then $P$". This is basically double negation elimination and is not intuitionistically valid. You are using the former.

Comment: In fact, what is even more common for intuitionistic systems is to define $\neg P$ as $P\to\bot$ in which case negation introduction is simply $\to$-introduction, and the law of non-contradiction is $\to$-elimination. I recommend this. That is, for intuitionistic reasoning, I recommend treating $\neg$ as a derived connective and forgetting about "RAA" and "proof by contradiction", and just use implication introduction and elimination plus the principle of explosion which is $\bot$-elimination.